# RESTHeart with windows-1251 charset

Tags: php, json, mongodb, restheart, windows-1251

- MongoDB server; Text data in windows-1251 charset.
- RESTHeart server.
- PHP with window-1251 charset making a request to RESTHeart.
- Text data  is broken

To get text "back" I use this code (from utf-8 to 1251, then from utf-8 to 1251, then back to utf-8, cause json throws an error if encoding is not utf-8):

```
$body = iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', iconv('UTF-8', 'CP1251//IGNORE', iconv('UTF-8', 'CP1251//IGNORE', $body)));
```

After this $body object contains normal text, but without some chars (not special, like cyrilic 'И').

Comment: I don't think you can convert rom utf-8 to 1251, then from utf-8 to 1251, then back to utf-8 without some information loss... I'd use either all 1251 or all UTF-8.

Comment: I would be happy to use UTF-8 everywhere, but now I have to work with what was done before me and that is quite difficult to remake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the charset for the JVM that executes RESTHeart with the `-Dfile.encoding property.`

Try something like:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=CP1251 -server -jar restheart.jar conf.yml
```

Comment: Thanks
Or java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -server -jar restheart.jar conf.yml